# Beeping server and no output from hpacucli commands

Tags: linux, raid, hp-proliant, supermicro, diskmanagement

I have a beeping supermicro server and my suspicion is that it's a RAID/disk issue. The supermicro storage is a separate unit to the manager (a HP Proliant Gen 9). 
As a result I've started attempting to discover some info about the RAID array and run this command:

```
lspci | grep RAID
```

which produces this output:

```
08:00.0 RAID bus controller: Hewlett-Packard Company Smart Array Gen9 Controllers (rev 01)
```

From what I've read (correct me if I'm wrong) this means the server is running Hewlett-Packard type RAID(?).
As a result I've installed hpacucli and run this command:

```
hpacucli ctrl all show config
```

The output of which is:

```
Error: No controllers detected.
```

The output of lsscsi is:

```
[0:0:0:0]    disk    HP       EF0450FARMV      HPD6  /dev/sdb 
[0:0:1:0]    disk    HP       EF0450FARMV      HPD6  /dev/sdc 
[0:0:2:0]    disk    HP       EF0450FARMV      HPD6  /dev/sdd 
[0:0:3:0]    disk    HP       EF0450FARMV      HPD6  /dev/sde 
[0:0:4:0]    disk    HP       EF0450FARMV      HPD6  /dev/sdf 
[0:0:5:0]    disk    HP       EF0450FARMV      HPD6  /dev/sdg 
[0:0:6:0]    disk    HP       EF0450FARMV      HPD6  /dev/sdh 
[0:0:7:0]    disk    HP       EF0450FARMV      HPD6  /dev/sdi 
[1:0:0:0]    disk    HP       LOGICAL VOLUME   1.34  /dev/sda 
[1:3:0:0]    storage HP       H241             1.34  -   

EDIT***
```

output of fdisk -l:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 720137.6 GB, 720137638731776 bytes, 1406518825648 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 262144 bytes / 23592960 bytes


Disk /dev/sdb: 450.1 GB, 450098159616 bytes, 879097968 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000f2d20

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048     1026047      512000   83  Linux
/dev/sdb2         1026048   879097855   439035904   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sdc: 450.1 GB, 450098159616 bytes, 879097968 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0005dd7d

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1            2048   879097855   439547904   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sdf: 450.1 GB, 450098159616 bytes, 879097968 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0007ed8a

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdf1            2048   879097855   439547904   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sdh: 450.1 GB, 450098159616 bytes, 879097968 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0004d03e

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdh1            2048   879097855   439547904   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sde: 450.1 GB, 450098159616 bytes, 879097968 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00027e6e

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sde1            2048   879097855   439547904   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sdd: 450.1 GB, 450098159616 bytes, 879097968 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000c0120

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1            2048   879097855   439547904   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sdg: 450.1 GB, 450098159616 bytes, 879097968 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000cbb24

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdg1            2048   879097855   439547904   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sdi: 450.1 GB, 450098159616 bytes, 879097968 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000b8bb0

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdi1            2048   879097855   439547904   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/cl-root: 53.7 GB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/cl-swap: 16.9 GB, 16911433728 bytes, 33030144 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/cl-home: 3529.6 GB, 3529569730560 bytes, 6893690880 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

This is all fairly new to me. Does anyone know why there is no output from the hpacucli command?

Comment: Can you pastebin your  `fdisk -l` output?

Comment: fdisk -l output added

Comment: Bummer. You're using LVM and Linux software RAID. You won't get hpssacli output from that controller without a firmware upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have an HP ProLiant Gen9 server and a Supermicro external JBOD enclosure for some reason.

HP servers don't beep when there are problems or failures; that's a silly way to alert of an issue. Supermicro equipment sometimes DOES beep when there's a problem.

The [HP H241](http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c04493355) is an HP-branded LSI SAS HBA.

The Supermicro JBOD has a few 450GB SAS disks in it. The enclosure *may* have a fan or power supply issue. Look for red lights.

Comment: There's a blue uid light flashing on the back of the storage (and yes I think it is a JBOD).

Comment: What's the make/model?